# Is there a possibility to define a global variable inside a class for Python GUI?

Tags: python, user-interface

```
import math
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import *
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import numpy as np
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.compat import StringIO
from pandas_datareader import data as web
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import yfinance as yf
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from statistics import mean
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import requests
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import calendar
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import random
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
from alpha_vantage.techindicators import TechIndicators
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import sys

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------


symbol = 'TSLA'




class Win1:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("400x400")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)


        symbol = Entry(root, text ='', bd=5)
        userInput1 = StringVar(None)
        self.master = Entry(root, textvariable=userInput1)
        self.master.pack()

        button1 = Button(root, text="Click Here", fg = 'blue', width=20)#, command=self.new_window("2", Win2))
        button1.pack(side='bottom',padx=15,pady=15)

        self.butnew("Hauptfunktionen", "2", Win2)
        self.butnew("Weitere Funktionen", "3", Win3)

        self.frame.pack()

    def butnew(self, text, number, _class):
        tk.Button(self.frame, text = text, command= lambda: self.new_window(number, _class)).pack(side='left')

    def new_window(self, number, _class):
        self.new = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        _class(self.new, number)


def config_plot():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    return(fig, ax)


class Win2:
    def __init__(self, master, number):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("1080x540")
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.fig, self.ax = config_plot()
        self.graphIndex = 0
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.master)
        self.config_window()

        self.quit = tk.Button(self.frame, text = f"Close this window", command = self.close_window)
        self.quit.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.draw_graph_one()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    def draw_graph_one(self):
        ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data1, meta_data1 = ts.get_monthly(symbol=symbol)
        df1 = data1['4. close']
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(df1)
        self.ax.set(title='Historical Chart')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------fertig
    def draw_graph_two(self):
        ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data2, meta_data2 = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbol, interval='1min', outputsize='compact')
        df2 = data2['4. close']
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(df2)
        self.ax.set(title='Intraday')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------fertig
    def draw_graph_three(self):
        ti = TechIndicators(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data3, meta_data3 = ti.get_bbands(symbol=symbol, interval='15min', time_period=30)
        df3 = data3

        ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data2, meta_data2 = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbol, interval='15min', outputsize='full')
        df2 = data2['4. close']

        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(df2, linestyle='-.')
        self.ax.plot(df3)
        self.ax.set(title='Bollinger Bands')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------fertig
    def draw_graph_four(self):
        ti = TechIndicators(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data44, meta_data44 = ti.get_sma(symbol=symbol, interval='30min', time_period=60)
        df44 = data44

        ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data1, meta_data1 = ts.get_intraday(symbol=symbol, interval='30min', outputsize='full')
        df1 = data1['4. close']

        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(df1)#, color='yellow')
        self.ax.plot(df44)#, color='black')
        self.ax.set(title='Simple Moving Average')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------fertig
    def draw_graph_five(self):
        ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data1, meta_data1 = ts.get_monthly(symbol=symbol)#, interval='1min', outputsize='full')
        df1 = data1['4. close']
        ts = TimeSeries(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        dataG, meta_dataG = ts.get_monthly(symbol='UCITS ETF')#, interval='1min', outputsize='full')
        dG = dataG['4. close']
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(df1)
        self.ax.plot(dG)
        self.ax.set(title='Comparision with Global Index')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def draw_graph_six(self):
        ti = TechIndicators(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data23, meta_data23 = ti.get_cci(symbol=symbol, interval='30min', time_period=60)
        df23 = data23

        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(df23)
        self.ax.set(title='Commodity Channel Index')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------fertig
    def draw_graph_seven(self):
        ti = TechIndicators(key='YOUR_API_KEY',output_format='pandas')
        data13, meta_data23 = ti.get_dx(symbol=symbol, interval='30min', time_period=60)
        df13 = data13

        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(df13)
        self.ax.set(title='Directional Movement Index')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def draw_graph_eight(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot()
        self.ax.set(title='Further Information')
        self.canvas.draw()
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def draw_graph_nine(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot()
        self.ax.set(title='Further Information')
        self.canvas.draw()


    def on_key_press(event):
        print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
        key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, toolbar)


    def config_window(self):
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)


        self.button_switch1 = Button(self.master, text="Historical Chart", command=self.draw_graph_one)
        self.button_switch1.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch2 = Button(self.master, text="Intraday", command=self.draw_graph_two)
        self.button_switch2.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch3 = Button(self.master, text="Bollinger Bands", command=self.draw_graph_three)
        self.button_switch3.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch4 = Button(self.master, text="SMA", command=self.draw_graph_four)
        self.button_switch4.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch5 = Button(self.master, text="Comparison with Index", command=self.draw_graph_five)
        self.button_switch5.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch6 = Button(self.master, text="CCI", command=self.draw_graph_six)
        self.button_switch6.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch7 = Button(self.master, text="DX", command=self.draw_graph_seven)
        self.button_switch7.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch8 = Button(self.master, text="Technical Analysis", command=self.draw_graph_eight)
        self.button_switch8.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.button_switch9 = Button(self.master, text="Technical Analysis", command=self.draw_graph_nine)
        self.button_switch9.pack(side=LEFT)

    def close_window(self):
        self.master.destroy()
root = tk.Tk()
app = Win1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

This is just a part of my code. My program consists of 3 windows, which are all similar built. But I have to input a string (Entry ...) and then this variable (symbol = Entry(....)) has to be valid through the whole program, inclusively other classes.
So my question is, how do I have to define the variable? I already tried global symbol, which didn't work.

Comment: How did you try global symbol? One would need to define global external to the classes and in the classes as well.

Comment: before symbol = Entry .... I wrote global symbol

Comment: The program opens a window, with the possibility to make an entry. Than the Entry has to be saved and is defined as symbol. Than the variable symbol is used in multiple classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make it a class variable:

```
class Win1:
    symbol = Entry(root, text ='', bd=5)
```

Then other code can access this by:

```
Win1.symbol
```

Comment: Well it didn't work as expected. Is there a possibility to define symbol within def as global variable?

Comment: When I enter the variable directly after Win1: and before def__init__......, then there comes the error, that root isn't defined, does that mean, that I have more or less to rewrite the def__init__(self, master): part?

Comment: The problem with my code is, that I have to have a first page/window, where I can entry a stock symbol (it works in the code), but then I have to define symbol as a global variable, but the window still has to be built up as before. So then when symbol is globally defined, I can use the variable for the second and third window.

Comment: You can move `root = tk.Tk()` up to where `symbol` was defined.

Comment: Ok I think I got, I will change the part and hope that it will work, thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a class which handles all windows, then put the symbol there, then pass the symbol as a parameter to all those windows.

Comment: Ok, could you show it with my code, because I'm not sure if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Nevermind the answer, I think this is better: Oh I see that the symbol entry was not pack() in win1, for umm Win2.... def __init__(self, master, number, entry_value): --> self.evalue = entry_value, and in   Win1 symbol_value = symbol.get() then pass symbol_value as evalue def new_window(self, number, _class, evalue):
        self.new = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        _class(self.new, number, evalue)

Comment: Ok I will try it